# What path do I use to call a background image in codeigniter

Tags: css, image, codeigniter

This is my root structure:

[image]

And under the folder css, I have the file style.css

I load my CSS file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print asset_url()?>css/style.css">
```

I created a helper asset_url_helper that has this function:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('asset_url()')) {
    function asset_url()
   {
    return base_url().'assets/';
   }
 }
```

And my .htacces file:

```
Deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Loading the CSS file works like a charm, thats no problem.

Now I want to call a background image from my style CSS something like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('/assets/img/bg-admin.jpg');
}
```

But this doesn't work

Can someone tell me how I call the image file from CSS?

Comment: You can try different paths from browsers Developer Tools like `firebug` extension in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`background-image: url()` in CSS works relatively.

Try this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../img/bg-admin.jpg');
}
```

This is assuming that your css file is in assets/css and not a sub folder of it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter will take the base_url. 
your url is http://localhost/rscms/external/bootstrap/css/style.css
you will to go back to bootstrap first come out from style.css then css then bootstrap

background-image: url('../../../img/bg-admin.jpg');