# How to set external custom font using css in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I want to set custom font to my application using Codeigniter.

I have set it but i think my url path is wrong.

font Path :

`localhost/example/user_assets/myfont.ttf`

I am doing this :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    url('/user_assets/user_assets/myfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('/user_assets/user_assets/myfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('/user_assets/user_assets/myfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  font-family: 'myFont';
}
```

Comment: What is the CSS path? try setting relative paths (to CSS file) instead of absolute ones

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989533/what-path-do-i-use-to-call-a-background-image-in-codeigniter

Comment: debug your web for example in google chrome inspector, and check which path your script try to access.

Comment: Check this [Custom Fonts in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409012/how-to-use-custom-fonts-and-icons-in-codeigniter)

Comment: try to change the path with `user_assets/user_assets/myfont.woff2` remove /